# How to make an image respect web page limits?

Tags: html, css, image, limit

I wanted to do this in CSS but javascript is ok too.

I have a png image I use as the menu bar that I put over my background image. Theres a part of the image that exceeds the page to the right.  I want it to just be cut out of the screen instead of strectching the web page and making a white line appear to the right of my background image.

Just in case the CSS:

```
position:absolute;
left:2%;
width:120%;
top:-220px;
height:700px;
z-index:6;
```

Any help is appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: Set it the width to `100%`? Or the parent to `overflow: hidden`?

Comment: we are going to need more info to answer : HTML and CSS of parent elements.

Comment: Thank you Putvande ! Was not aware of that property!

Answer (score 0):

May be set the width to 100% or less!

Answer (score 0):

how about background-size: cover;

```
#abc {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/nvH8nI3.jpg) 50% 0 repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```